# How can I do the same thing that "any?" in Ruby does in PHP

Tags: php

In Ruby, `any?` takes a block and check if given collection has a value that fulfills the block like this:

```
[1, 2, 3].any? {|v| v > 2} # true
```

Is there any way to do this in PHP?  My current idea is to use `array_reduce()`:

```
array_reduce(array(1, 2, 3), function($acc, $val) {
    return $acc || ($val > 2);
}, false);
```

But it will itereate all elements in the array, so I guess it's not as good as "any?" in Ruby.  How can I return the boolean value as soon as expected value is found in PHP?

Comment: What's the matter with a simple `for` loop?

Comment: do you mean like this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: yeah, but `in_array()` can't take function as an argument.

Comment: You should take a look at [functional-php](https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php) which is a library that provides `any` and many other functional collection primitives.

Comment: `But it will itereate all elements in the array, so I guess it's not as good as "any?" in Ruby` How do you think `any` works?

Comment: @igorw wow, functional-php looks great! Thanks for letting me know it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit `any?` in Ruby iterates given collection from its top, and exit the iteration when it finds expected element.  This snippet is for illustration https://gist.github.com/mahata/5225084 - "4" and "5" are not printed.

Answer (score 0):

You're too keen about functional programming. PHP is not a functional language; at least that is not its main job.

```
$array = array(1,2,3);
foreach ($array as $value) {
    if ($value > 2) return $value;
}
```

Comment: solution by @deceze is better if you want to have a arbitrary test case, but a simple for loop just makes things less complicated and reduces the *very slight* overhead of function calls.

Comment: Thanks!  I expected PHP to have something like `in_array()` that takes function as an argument, but it's simple enough.

Answer (score 0):

```
function any(array $array, callable $test) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if ($test($value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

You could use a simple `array_filter` instead, but it will iterate the whole array every time:

```
if (array_filter($array, function ($v) { return $v > 2; })) ...
```

Comment: Thanks! `array_filter()` has the same problem that I suggested with `array_reduce()`, but making it as a function with `foreach` looks good enough for this case.